# Add sweet alert 2 to a jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This function is called when i submit the modal

```
function saveData() {

var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var phone = $('#phone').val();
var address = $('#address').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "server.php?p=add",
    data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone + "&address=" + address,
    success: function () {
        viewData();
    }
});
}
```

And i can't add the sweet alert when the modal is submitted

```
    swal({
        title: "Success!",
        text: "added!",
        type: "success",
        timer: 3000,
        showConfirmButton: false
    });
```

Comment: where did you call swal in you ajax call?

Comment: in the success function.

Comment: what is the returning value?what you console log?

Comment: [Tue Oct 11 09:51:58 2016] ::1:56213 [302]: /server.php?p=add
[Tue Oct 11 09:51:58 2016] ::1:56215 [200]: /
[Tue Oct 11 09:51:58 2016] ::1:56216 [200]: /index.php
[Tue Oct 11 09:51:58 2016] ::1:56217 [200]: /css/sweetalert2.css
[Tue Oct 11 09:51:58 2016] ::1:56218 [200]: /css/style.css
[Tue Oct 11 09:51:58 2016] ::1:56219 [200]: /js/sweetalert2.js
[Tue Oct 11 09:51:58 2016] ::1:56220 [200]: /js/index.js
[Tue Oct 11 09:51:58 2016] ::1:56221 [200]: /js/jquery.js
[Tue Oct 11 09:51:58 2016] ::1:56222 [200]: /server.php

Comment: I mean is there any error in your console ?

Comment: put the jquery first and than sweetalertjs in you scripts

Comment: no... and that is the problem, i can't figure out where is the problem.

Comment: i already tried that, and not working...

Comment: show your console log. You can copy and paste 
swal({
        title: "Success!",
        text: "added!",
        type: "success",
        timer: 3000,
        showConfirmButton: false
    });
to your console log, to debug swal error, request error or function show alert never call.

Comment: in console log runs... swal({ title: "Success!", text: "added!", type: "success", timer: 3000, showConfirmButton: false });
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}

Answer (score 0):

In the end i figure out the solution

```
function saveData() {
var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var phone = $('#phone').val();
var address = $('#address').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "server.php?p=add",
    data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone + "&address=" + address,
    success: function () {
        $('#addData').modal('hide');
        swal({
            title: "Success!",
            text: "added!",
            type: "success",
            timer: 3000,
            showConfirmButton: false
        });
        viewData();
    }
});
};
```

And need to be careful to run the script in a certain order:

> 1. jquery.js
> 2. bootstrap.js